# ImportError: No module named Window but from import works

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The pyspark documentation for the Window class starts as: `class pyspark.sql.Window` But if one executes the code:

```python
import pyspark.sql.Window
```

one gets the following error:

> `ImportError: No module named Window`

On the other hand if one executes the code:

```python
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

no error is produced.

This seems to be incongruous. Is this an error in the documentation?

Comment: yes it did throw error may be they have removed the package from that path

Comment: `pyspark.sql.Window` is not a module, it is a class. When you do `import foo`, you can only import a module. The same thing would happen if you tried `import decimal.Decimal` or `import datetime.datetime`

Comment: @pault that is true but the docs show Window in the sql namespace not in the window module.

Comment: @dmbaker please provide a link to the docs you are referring to

Comment: @pault: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window

Answer (score 8):

`pyspark.sql.window` is the module. This module has an attribute `Window`. 
You can either

```
import pyspark.sql.window as W
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

You can not do `import pyspark.sql.Window`

python language is case sensitive so `window` and `Window` are two completely different things.